# Mysql Right join with mutiple condtion not working

Tags: mysql

i have two table table1 and table2 and when right joining the table2 with table1 and i am not getting the row. here i have attached the fiddle link also

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
 `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`orderid`)
);
CREATE TABLE `table2` ( `fields_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `table1_order_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , `field_value` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , `fname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`fields_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`orderid`) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'karthi', 'name');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '2', 'karthi', 'name');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '3', 'selva', 'name');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'salem', 'city');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '2', 'chennai', 'city');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`fields_id`, `table1_order_id`, `field_value`, `fname`) VALUES (NULL, '3', 'mumbai', 'city');

select table1.*
from table1 
right JOIN table2 ON (
        table2.table1_order_id = table1.orderid 
        AND 
            ( table2.field_value LIKE '%karthi%' 
            AND table2.fname = 'name' ) 
        AND ( 
            table2.field_value LIKE '%salem%' 
            AND table2.fname = 'city' 
        ) 

    ) 

    where 1 group by table1.orderid
```

Above i wrote select query but it returns null result, but i am expecting output like below,

orderid 1

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table2.fname cannot be both 'city' and 'name' in the same row.

To get both of this EAV model we use two joins on the table2 with a different alias.

Its unclear why you want a RIGHT JOIN. Normal [inner] JOIN is fine.

I've moved the selection to a WHERE criteria just for ease of readability. Because its inner it could be put in the `ON` criteria.

While you can `group by table1.orderid` when you do this you cannot `SELECT table1.*` because by grouping their is only one row per orderid and therefore multiple orders matching the same critera cannot return on the same line (without an aggregate function like `GROUP_CONCAT`).

```
select table1.*
from table1 
inner JOIN table2 t2name ON 
        t2name.table1_order_id = table1.orderid 
inner JOIN table2 t2city ON 
        t2city.table1_order_id = table1.orderid 

where
    t2name.fname = 'name' 
    AND t2name.field_value LIKE '%karthi%' 
    AND t2city.fname = 'city'
    AND t2city.field_value LIKE '%salem%'
```

or

```
select table1.orderid
from table1 
inner JOIN table2 t2name ON 
        t2name.table1_order_id = table1.orderid 
inner JOIN table2 t2city ON 
        t2city.table1_order_id = table1.orderid     
where
    t2name.fname = 'name' 
    AND t2name.field_value LIKE '%karthi%' 
    AND t2city.fname = 'city'
    AND t2city.field_value LIKE '%salem%' 
group by table1.orderid
```

Comment: Thanks saved my days

Comment: You're welcome. Also see [eav guide for mysql](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)

Comment: your works fine. thanks for sharing the eav guide. now the problem i need to search on more than 50 column or more on that.

Comment: I'd seriously start looking at full text search engines like solr and see how they work with mysql datasources.